# HDMI not working with TV and on Linux

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a dual boot Ubuntu/Win10 on my PC. When I started it today the picture was pinkish on Ubuntu so I naturally reinserted the HDMI cable into the TV that I use as a monitor. It didn't work.

The next thing I tried is using another monitor. I sometimes got the picture but when I used the cable on the TV I got nothing.

I connected the other monitor and rebooted my PC, going into Win10. Now every time I inserted the HDMI cable into the TV I get no picture but when I insert it into the other monitor I get it. Every single time. On Ubuntu it was successful 1 out of 7 times.

If the TV didn't work but monitor did, I would think that the problem is with the TV. If both the monitor and TV didn't work, I would think that the problem is with the GPU. BUT, the Win10/monitor combo always works, Ubuntu/monitor sometimes and TV never.

Bootloader shows on the monitor by the way.

I am at loss at what is happening and what might be the problem. I will try using another HDMI cable when I get/find it.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: There may be just a issue with the tv or gpu setting the correct resolution. I experienced it once at work where we had to force a specific resolution in windows as soon as it loads. Otherwise it would not recognize the tv.

Comment: @Randomhero yes, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the HDMI cable fixed the problem.

I'm still not sure why the TV didn't work and the monitor did with the old one.